# Как подтянуть по ID ФИО клиета и добавить эти данные в другую таблица?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть модель клиента.

```
 [Table("Clients")]
public class Client : Person
{
    [Key]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string ClientFIO { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string ThirdName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public int Pasport { get; set; }
```

Есть модель абонемента:

```
[Table("TypeOfSubscriptions")]
public class TypeOfSubscription
{
    [Key]
    public int TypeOfSubscriptionId { get; set; }

    public string SubscriptionName { get; set; }

    public int VisitQty { get; set; }

    public int SubscriptionCost { get; set; }
}
```

Есть модель привязки Клиет-Абонемент абонемента:

```
 [Table("Subscriptions")]
public class Subscription
{
    [Key]
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string ClientFIO { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActivationDate { get; set; }
    public string SubscriptionType { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<TypeOfSubscription> SubTypes { get; set; }


}
```

Есть список клиентов и ссылка, которая должна направлять на добавление абонемента для этого клиента.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как это реализовать ? Если прописывать в контроллере для создания абонемента, то как подтягивать данные из клиента ??
Хочу чтобы из меню на скрине, переходя по ссылку "Добавить абонемент" сразу подтягивались данные этого клиента (ClientId и ClientFIO) и там реализовать выбор из списка доступных абонементов.
Потому как пресловутых Ивановых Иванов Ивановичей может быть как всегда несколько.

**UPD**

Попытался решить таким способом:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateSubscription(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Client client = db.Clients.Find(id);


        Subscription subscription = new Subscription();
        subscription.SubTypes = db.TypesOfSubscriptions.ToList<TypeOfSubscription>();
        subscription.ClientId = client.ClientId;
        subscription.ClientFIO = client.ToString();
        subscription.ActivationDate = DateTime.Now;



        SelectList subscriptions = new SelectList(db.TypesOfSubscriptions, "SubscriptionName", "SubscriptionName");
        ViewBag.TypesOfSubscr = subscriptions;


        return View(subscription);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateSubscription([Bind(Include = "SubscriptionId,ClientId,ClientFIO,ActivationDate,SubscriptionType")] Subscription subscription)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {


            db.Subscriptions.Add(subscription);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View();
    }

}
```

Но столкнулся с такой штукой:
При заполнении формы, если поле без выпадающего списка, то всё сохраняется, если с выпадающим, то SubscriptionType остаётся пустым.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в результате получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же боле без списка оставить незаполненным, то в результате вместо "Мяу" будет пустая ячейка. 
Вероятно это происходит из-за того, что инициализирую все поля кроме SubscriptionType сразу в методе, но почему не работает поле со списком и как сделать процесс передачи данных из другой таблицы иначе не знаю

Использовал 2 варианта реализации выпадающего списка:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubscriptionType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SubscriptionType, new SelectList(Model.SubTypes, "SubscriptionName", "SubscriptionName"), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "repeatForPosition" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubTypes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubscriptionType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("SubscriptionType", ViewBag.TypesOfSubscr as SelectList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubscriptionType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPD после комментариев tCOde**

Что я получил в итоге и что не работает:

1.Созданы 2 переменные в модели Subscription:

```
 [NotMapped]
    public List<SelectListItem> SubType { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int SelectedSubscriptionType { get; set; }
```

2.Обновлён метод:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateSubscription(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Client client = db.Clients.Find(id);

        var dbData = new List<TypeOfSubscription>();
        Subscription subscription = new Subscription { SubType = new List<SelectListItem>() };
        foreach(var item in dbData)
        {
            subscription.SubType.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = item.TypeOfSubscriptionId.ToString(),
                Text = item.SubscriptionName

            });

        }
        subscription.ClientId = client.ClientId;
        subscription.ClientFIO = client.ToString();
        subscription.ActivationDate = DateTime.Now;

       SelectList subscriptions = new SelectList(db.TypesOfSubscriptions, "SubscriptionName", "SubscriptionName");
        ViewBag.TypesOfSubscr = subscriptions;


        return View(subscription);
    }
```

3.Элемент DropDownListFor имеет следующий вид в представлении:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubscriptionType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSubscriptionType, Model.SubType, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "repeatForPosition" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubscriptionType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Теперь из поля со списком ничего не выпадает :)

Comment: в чем проблема-то????

Comment: @tCode проблема в том, чтобы заполнить SubscriptionType из поля со списком. На данный момент программа игнорирует всё, что бы я не выбрал из этого списка и не передаёт ничего

Comment: покажите код view с выпадающим списком

Comment: @tCode обновил пост

Comment: Нну. Я бы для начала определился, будет ли в БД таблица SubscriptionType с полями Id, Title а потом уже задумываться о выпадающих списках и том, как их делать. Косвенно вы сами об этом говорите в комментариях - "а если добавится новое значение в базу"?

Comment: @AK Добрый день, да, такая таблица в бд есть, обновил пост с моделью этой таблицы

Comment: Ну а теперь вернитесь к ответу - вам дали всё верно, осталось только `// список для вывода во view` поменять - из базы прочитать (что-то типа `db.TypeOfSubscription.Select(x => new {Text = x.SubscriptionName, Value = x.TypeOfSubscriptionId})`), а не сгенерить на лету.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно иметь в модели `List<SelectListItem>` - элементы для выпадающего списка и переменную, в которой будет передаваться выбранное значение из view в controller, в примере ниже это `public int SelectedSubscriptionType { get; set; }`

**Model**

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    // здесь будет храниться выбранное значение из выпадающего списка во view
    public int SelectedSubscriptionType { get; set; }

    // список для вывода во view
    public List<SelectListItem> SubscriptionType =>
        // здесь ваша инициализация, моя для примера, инициализировать можете и в контроллере перед выводом view
        new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "First",
                Value = "1"
            },
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "Second",
                Value = "2"
            }
        };
}
```

**View**

```
@model SomeViewModel
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSubscriptionType, Model.SubscriptionType)
```

В итоге будет создан выпадающий список и при `submit` формы выбранное значение вы получите в переменной `SelectedSubscriptionType`

**Инициализация списка в контроллере**

```
var dbData = new List<TypeOfSubscription>(); // получаете данные из БД
var model = new SomeViewModel
{
    SubscriptionType = new List<SelectListItem>()
};

foreach (var item in dbData)
{
    model.SubscriptionType.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = item.Id.ToString(),
        Text = item.Type
    });
}

return View(model);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если пользователь с доступом захочет добавить новый вид абонемента, ему надо лезть в код ?

Comment: как вы будете формировать сам список это ваше дело, как сделаете так и будет. захардкодите - придется лезть в код, а если сделаете в БД - достаточно будет добавить абонемент в БД. В контроллере подтягиваете из БД абонементы и формируете List<SelectListItem> из этих данных для модели

Comment: Я не совсем понял как сделать этот список selectListItem-ов в моём случае. Создал переменную SubType типа LIst<SelectListItem> в модели. Как мне в контроллере наполнить её значениями из бд ? db.TypesOfSubscription.ToLIst<TypesOdSubscription>(),  дальше что и куда ?

Comment: по примеру как описана инициализация в `Model`, тоже самое и в контроллере `var model = new SomeViewModel();` и дальше инициализируете список

Comment: Вопрос в том, как привести всё это мероприятие к SelectListItem?
1.Я создал пременную SybType типа LIst<SelectListItem> в модели
2.Создаю экземпляр класса этой модели в контроллере.
3.Присваиваю этой переменной новый объект типа List<SelectListItem>
4.Где-то как-то прописываю db.TypesOfSubscription.ToLIst<TypesOdSubscription>()
И как всё это соединить ? )

Comment: добавил пример, в модели соответственно делаете `public List<SelectListItem> SubscriptionType { get; set; }`

Comment: Обновил пост. Всё сделал по инструкции, теперь ничего не выпадает из списка

Comment: @AndreyGrek ну естественно, в `dbData` вы должны положить данные из бд, а не пустой лист создавать, в примере я создал пустой лист, потому что у меня нет конкретных данных, я же специально комментарий к этой строчке написал